# What is the fastest way to convert a boolean array to bytes in Scala?

Tags: arrays, scala, optimization, binary

After implementing the huffman algorithm in Scala, I'm now left with a array of bits with a length of over 10.000. Now I want to convert this array to bytes and write it to a file in the fastest way possible.

I currently have the following algorithm:

```
val bits = encode(createCodeTree(fileChars))(fileChars)
val string = new StringBuilder
for(List(b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,b8) <- bits.grouped(8)) string.append(bitsToByte(b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,b8))

 def bitsToByte(bits : Boolean*) : Char = {
    var amount = 0;
    for(i <- 1 until bits.length){
      amount += (if(bits(i-1)) 1 else 0) * scala.math.pow(2,i).intValue()
    }
    amount.toChar
  }
```

I was wondering if there is room for improvement (because I don't think creating a new list every time is very optimized). Also, I was wondering if it is possible that this gives incorrect results due to using `for(List(b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,b8) <- bits.grouped(8))` on a list where `bits.length%8!=0`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if this is much faster, but it's certainly more concise.

```
bits.grouped(8)
    .map(_.foldLeft(0)((i,b) => (i<<1) + (if(b) 1 else 0)).toChar)
    .mkString
```

I also think this bits->byte->char translation is more correct.

This assumes that the bits are most-to-least significant, left-to-right. If that's not the case then change the `fold` from `.foldLeft(0)((i,b) =>...` to `.foldRight(0)((b,i) =>...`

Comment: I definately misconverted some bits using that previous algorithm. Thanks!